# Date and Time column validation for SharePoint List using time as a variable

Tags: list, sharepoint

I Have a Date and Tine column in my SharePoint list. If someone fills out the field and uses a time after 8AM I would like a message to appear to please use the following business days date at 7AM. Is this possible with SharePoint List column validation?

I have tried some basic validation but do not know if I am using the right formulas or if this is even possible.

Comment: I have tested validation formula provided by Ganesh Sanap and it works well. Please check.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Column Validation** formula like below for your SharePoint date and time column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([DateColumn]),TRUE,IF(ROUND(TIME(HOUR([DateColumn]),Minute([DateColumn]),Second([DateColumn])),2)>0.33,FALSE,TRUE))
```

Where `DateColumn` is the display name of date and time column and `0.33` is equivalent number to 08:00AM which is calculated by dividing 24 hrs in a day like `=8/24`.

Similarly, you can adjust the formula as per your requirements (for 7AM or 8AM or any other time in a day).

Column Settings:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.